# How to generate blank favicon programatically?

Tags: asp.net, favicon

I have no favicon on my web site so there are numerous of failed log entry and I decided to rewrite favicon.ico get request to a page that will generate blank file and return it to a browser?

How do you think, is it possible? Could you please help me a bit how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[dummyimage.com](http://dummyimage.com/16x16/ff/ff.png)

or

[ipsumimage.appspot.com](http://ipsumimage.appspot.com/16x16.png?b=f&f=f)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to create a physical file, I would suggest adding

```
<link href="data:image/x-icon;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQEAYAAABPYyMiAAAABmJLR0T///////8JWPfcAAAACXBIWXMAAABIAAAASABGyWs+AAAAF0lEQVRIx2NgGAWjYBSMglEwCkbBSAcACBAAAeaR9cIAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
```

in the head section

Source http://davidwalsh.name/blank-favicon

Comment: Is it really necessary to add that long base64? I tried an empty value `data:image/x-icon;base64,` and  no errors were reported neither in the console nor in the html validator

Answer (score 2):

If you really want it to be blank, I would generate a blank file and place it there. Generating it seems overkill/unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

I am using just

```
<link rel="icon" href="data:image/x-icon;base64,AA">
```

I wrote an article about it here https://fibo.github.io/2021/02/empty-favicon-trick/

Answer (score 1):

You need a white 16x16 .ico file placed somewhere on your site subfolders, usually "img/favicon.ico"

Then add a refference to this file in yout masterpage

```
<head runat="server">
    <link rel="Icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicon.ico" />
</head>
```

Comment: In your code, you used the MIME type `image/png` and an `.ico` file. That's inconsistent.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the minimal data URI.

```
<link rel="icon" href="data:," />
```

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

> The minimal data URI is `data:,,` consisting of the scheme, no
> media-type, and zero-length data.